# iOS 8 custom framework linking issues

Tags: ios, xcode, templates, frameworks

I'm having issues linking to my custom iOS framework which make me realize I don't fully understand the concepts behind this process.

Basically I have a framework project created using the new Cocoa Touch Framework template, and a client project that uses the framework.  If I add the framework xcodeproj file to the client project everything works fine.  But if I have the 2 projects side-by-side in a workspace I can't get the client project to recognize the framework.  I've tried adding it as a link binary but it displays in red, and I've tried adding the header @import statement (which produces the error "unable to build module").

I'm unclear what files the framework should produce as output and where it should put them (I can't find any), and what is needed for the client project to recognize them.  Does the OS (or simulator) take care of locating them or does the client have to reference a specific location? Why (and how) does it work when the xcodeproj file is included in the client?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. I can't seem to find enough documentation about the subject. If you want to give me an email which is my first name last name @ gmail.com all lower case no separators between the first and last name maybe we can work on it together. Pool our limited knowledge.